# Paste a text to textarea in browser control in Vb.Net

Tags: vb.net, browser, webbrowser-control

How can I paste a text to the text area within a form in the browser control?

I think how i have selected is correct

```
 browser1.Document.Forms.GetElementsByName("editform").GetElementsByName("input")
```

**UPDATE**:Here is the Html

```
....
<form name="editform">
<textarea name="input">
</textarea>
</form>
...
```

Comment: Can you give a sample of the HTML as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out it's not possible due to security reasons.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how it can be done based on the HTML you've provided. You must first add a reference to [MSHTML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa741317%28VS.85%29.aspx) via the `Microsoft.mshtml`. Also, I would recommed adding an [`id`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533880%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) attribute to the text area then you can get to it much easier. Something along these lines.

```
<form name="editform"> 
    <textarea id="myTextArea" name="input"> 
    </textarea> 
</form>
```

Then you can set the [`value`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535122%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) property of the text area.

```
Dim textArea As HTMLTextAreaElement

textArea = WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("myTextArea").DomElement
textArea.value = "Hello World!"
```